# Como separar as palavras de uma string?

Tags: php

Como eu separo as palavras dessa *string* em variáveis separadas com PHP?

Eu gostaria de fazer algo assim:

```
$frase = "O + rato + roeu + a + roupa + do + rei + de + roma";

for(i=1; i<=**numero de palavras**; i++)
{
    $palavra + i = //Uma palavra por variável sem o sinal de adição.
}
```

E quero que o resultado final fique assim — cada palavra numa variável diferente

```
var1 = O;
var2 = rato;
var3 = roeu;
var4 = a;
var5 = roupa;
var6 = do;
var7 = rei;
var8 = de;
var9 = roma;
```

Answer (score 8):

Tem várias maneiras mas acho que o melhor será um array com [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$frase = "O + rato + roeu + a + roupa + do + rei + de + roma";
$palavras = explode('+', $frase);
```

Agora tem um array, fazendo `print_r($palavras);`:

> Array ( [0] => O [[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)] => rato [[2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)] => roeu [3] => a [4] => roupa [5] => do [6] => rei [7] => de [8] => roma )

Pode aceder a qualquer uma das palavras através do seu index dentro deste array, base 0:

```
$palavras[0] = ' O ';
$palavras[1] = ' rato ';
...
```

Se quiser volta-las a juntar numa frase sem os sinais de adição basta fazer um [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$frase = implode('', $palavras); // não coloco espaço no primeiro argumento pois este já existe em cada uma das palavras do nosso array
```

E fica:

> O rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma

No entanto fazendo o que pediu, usando o ciclo for e havendo uma variável dinâmica para cada palavra (neste contexto não recomendo) pode fazer:

```
$frase = "O + rato + roeu + a + roupa + do + rei + de + roma";
$palavras = explode('+', $frase);
for($i = 0, $count = count($palavras); $i < $count; $i++) {
    $varNum = $i+1;
    ${'var' . $varNum} = $palavras[$i];
}
echo $var1; // O
...
echo $var9; // roma
```

Answer (score 1):

Se for como variável numerada tipo:

```
$variavel0 = "valor0";
$variavel1 = "valor1";
...
```

Eu faria assim:

```
$frase = "O + rato + roeu + a + roupa + do + rei + de + roma";
$palavras = explode(" + ", $frase);

//com variaveis numeradas

for($x = 0; $x < count($palavras); $x++){

    $valTemp = "\$variavel".$x." = \"".$palavras[$x]."\";";
    eval($valTemp);
    echo $valTemp."</br>";

}
```

Você consegue depois usar essas variáveis. Exemplo:

```
echo $variavel4;
// a saída será: roupa
```

Comment: Perfeito Andrei, Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo @abduzeedo... be happy =)

Comment: Nao esquece de aprovar a resposta @abduzeedo. Abraço